# azure pipeline strategy matrix with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, azure-devops, devops

There i want build in azure with matrix for my service in docker compose

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
  tags:
    include:
      - '*'

pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals ci-cd-agent

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  - name: gitTag
    ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/') }}:
      value: $[variables['Build.SourceBranchName']]
    ${{ else }}:
      value: ''

stages:
  - stage: BuildAndPush
    displayName: Build and Push
    jobs:
      - job: BuildAndPushServices
        strategy:
          matrix:
            RabbitMQ: { serviceName: 'npo-rabbitmq' }
            Seq: { serviceName: 'npo-seq' }
            RateAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-rate-api' }
            BalanceAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-balance-api' }
            SMSAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-sms-api' }
            ClientAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-client-api' }
            ContactAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-contact-api' }
            ContractAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-contract-api' }
            CreditAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-credit-api' }
            DocumentStorageAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-document-storage-api' }
            DocumentRecognizeAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-document-recognize-api' }
            FaceAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-face-api' }
            FcbAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-fcb-api' }
            LoanAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-loan-api' }
            CreditRegistrationAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-credit-registration-api' }
            IdentityAPI: { serviceName: 'npo-identity-api' }
            SagaOrchestrationStateMachine: { serviceName: 'npo-saga-orchestration-state-machine' }
            Prometheus: { serviceName: 'npo-prometheus' }
            Grafana: { serviceName: 'npo-grafana' }
            AlertManagerBot: { serviceName: 'npo-alertmanager-bot' }
            AlertManager: { serviceName: 'npo-alertmanager' }
            Alpine: { serviceName: 'npo-alpine' }
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Service Name before Docker task is: $(serviceName)"
            displayName: 'Debug - Print Service Name Before Docker Task'

          - script: ls -la
            displayName: 'List directory contents'

          - script: cat docker-compose.yml
            displayName: 'Show docker-compose.yml'

          - script: echo "Current service name is $(serviceName)"
            displayName: "Debug - Show current service name before build"

          - task: DockerCompose@0
            displayName: 'Build $(serviceName)'
            inputs:
              action: 'Build service'
              dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
              serviceName: '$(serviceName)'

          - script: |
              echo "Service Name after Docker task is: $(serviceName)"
            displayName: 'Debug - Print Service Name After Docker Task'

          - task: DockerCompose@0
            displayName: 'Push $(serviceName)'
            inputs:
              action: 'Push service'
              dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
              serviceName: '$(serviceName)'

          - script: |
              echo "Service Name after Push is: $(serviceName)"
            displayName: 'Debug - Print Service Name After Push'

  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy
        steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: 'Bake and Deploy K8s manifests'
            inputs:
              action: bakeAndDeploy
              kubernetesServiceConnection: npo
              namespace: npo
              manifests: '$(bake.manifestsBundle)'
              imagePullSecrets: 'myregistrykey'

  - stage: Cleanup
    displayName: Cleanup
    jobs:
      - job: Cleanup
        steps:
          - script: |
              kubectl delete NetworkPolicy -n npo s-default --kubeconfig=/root/.kube/config
            displayName: 'Delete Network Policy'
```

in docker-compose service names is correct. but i catch error "The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"

in log i have
Show docker-compose.yml - show correct
Debug - Show current service name before build - "Current service name is npo-credit-api"
Build npo-credit-api - ##[error]The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Comment: i fix build with
        steps:
          - script: echo Building and pushing $(serviceName)
          - script: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build $(serviceName)
            displayName: 'Build $(serviceName)'
            condition: and(ne(variables['serviceName'], ''), ne(variables['serviceName'], ''))

Comment: now failed when push

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still need an answer to this, but I had the same exact problem and ended up here.  For you and others that might end up here...

You have the following task style built:

```
- task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: 'Push $(serviceName)'
    inputs:
       action: 'Push service'
       dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
       serviceName: '$(serviceName)'
```

In my case, I had something very similar where the build was failing, but found the issue to be the action line.   You have (and I did too), "Push service", but it should be "Push services", note the pluralization.   As soon as I changed this, it worked for me.

Comment: yes its correct but how to push to kubernates?